# c# - cannot delete the last remaining item in listview

Tags: c#, listview, listviewitem

I am working on a project (simple phone book) for personal use. I am having trouble deleting the last remaining item in my listview (listView1). Here you can take a look how it looks like:

[image]

So, let's say that I have got 5 contacts in the list and when I try to remove all of them, it's not possible. It is possible to remove only 4 of them. When I try to remove all of them and then close/run the application, there will be no removed contacts. When I try to remove 4 of them and I close/run the program, they would be deleted. When I try to remove the last one, it is not possible either. When I close/run app it would always remain there.

Since it doesn't makes sense to upload the whole code here, you can take a closer look at it at this [link](http://www.sendspace.com/file/ugiz30).

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I've scanned through your code a little, looks like you don't have any the so-called `RemoveAll` method. There is just one method called `Remove`. That method seems to remove only 1 selected item at a time. Could you describe more about how you remove all the items with that `Remove` method?

Comment: Valid code: Dim x As New ListView x.Items.Clear()

Comment: You also have an empty Catch in your remove method, so maybe some type of exception is getting eaten up when you try to do the last remove. Have you tried debugging it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for removing items from the listview:

```
Person person = new Person();
try { person = FindPerson(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text); } catch { return; }
if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
try
{
if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 0) return;
foreach (ListViewItem eachItem in listView1.SelectedItems)
{
people.RemoveAll(x => x.Name == eachItem.Text);
listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].Selected = true;
listView1.Items.Remove(eachItem);
}
}
catch { }
ClearAll();
ReadOnlyON();
}
else
{
MessageBox.Show("Nothing is selected!", "Notification", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Comment: Working like a clock, TYVM once again!

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you can use the clear method to remove the last item.

```
ListView1.Clear();
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.clear(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.clear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: This will only remove items temporary in the listview!I need it to be deleted from xml file as well! When I load the program again, the remaining item will still be there.

Comment: Ah does your current program remove the item in the xml file when you run the delete function?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the list backwards and remove each item or use as suggested ListView1.Clear();

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this line

```
 listView1.SelectedItems[0].Remove();
```

in Remove()
with

```
foreach ( ListViewItem eachItem in listView1.SelectedItems)
{
    listView1.Items.Remove(eachItem);
}
```

SelectedItems[0].Remove(); does not work for last item.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I delete items:

```
void Rmv()
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this contact?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Remove();
        }
        else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    void Remove()
    {
            if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                Person person = new Person();
                person = FindPerson(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text);
                people.RemoveAt(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index);
                foreach (ListViewItem eachItem in listView1.SelectedItems)
                {
                    listView1.Items.Remove(eachItem);
                }
                textBox1.Text = "";
                textBox2.Text = "";
                textBox3.Text = "";
                textBox4.Text = "";
                textBox5.Text = "";
                textBox6.Text = "";
                dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
                if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
                {
                    textBox1.ReadOnly = false;
                    textBox2.ReadOnly = false;
                    textBox3.ReadOnly = false;
                    textBox4.ReadOnly = false;
                    textBox5.ReadOnly = false;
                    textBox6.ReadOnly = false;
                    dateTimePicker1.Enabled = true;
                    UserCount();
                }
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Nothing is selected! ", "Notification", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
    }


    void UserCount()
    {
        try
        {
            if ((listView1.Items.Count) == 0)
            {
                toolStripLabel1.Text = Convert.ToString(listView1.Items.Count) + "& contacts";
            }
            else if ((listView1.Items.Count) == 1)
            {
                toolStripLabel1.Text = Convert.ToString(listView1.Items.Count) + "& contact";
            }
            else
            {
                toolStripLabel1.Text = Convert.ToString(listView1.Items.Count) + "& contacts";
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```